# One-Way Data Binding in Angular

Tags: html, angular

```
<ng-select style="width: 350px; background: white"  id="wslr_name" name="wslr_name"  
                        [searchable]="true" [editableSearchTerm]="true"  appendTo="body" [closeOnSelect]="true" [markFirst]="true" [items]="wslrList.result" bindLabel="A" bindValue="B"
                        [ngModel]="Group.wslr_name" (ngModelChange)="wslrSelect($event)" >
                        <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
                        {{item.A}}
```

How to replace [ngModel] with one way data binding?

Comment: remove ngModelChange and it will be one way binded.

Comment: (ngModelChange)="wslrSelect($event)" ==> if I remove it then what about "wslrSelect($event)"there will be no problem?

Comment: what one way you want? template to ts or ts to template?

Comment: want to change from ts to template

Comment: remove [ngModel] and keep (ngModelChange)

Comment: okay ! wil try it thanks for help